# Javascript - comparing loaction.pathname not working as expected with or operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, compare

I am trying to get the loacation.pathname of the current page and compare it to see if its /Login or /Register, if it is one of those the code in the if should not be executed.

**Code:**

```
if (location.pathname != '/Login' || location.pathname != '/Register')
     {
       prevView.push(location.href); // Add View to PreviousView so when needed we can navigate back to previous Page/View
       prevView.shift(); // Remove the First element from the array
     }
```

**I also tried:**

```
if ((location.pathname != '/Login') || (location.pathname != '/Register')
```

**and**

```
 if (((location.pathname != '/Login') || (location.pathname != '/Register')))
```

But not working - what am I doing wrong.

[image: img1]

[image: Img2]

Comment: Review boolean logic. You need `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: Could you please check the value of location.pathname by logging into the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an `||` and therefore it will always fail.
You have to use `&&`.

```
if (location.pathname != '/Login' && location.pathname != '/Register')
```

Let me break it down in human language.
if my location pathname equals /login OR my location pathname equals /register, I want you to do something. (the == variant)

However....

(now comes the "is not" variant, the one you are using) If my location pathname does not equal /login... oh wait, it does! so the "return" value is false! Let us move on to my other statement... OR it does not equal /register, which is true! go into this block of code!

Comment: What a stupid mistake - now it works thanks

Comment: @Stefan27 happens to the best of us. Please accept the answer if it was the correct answer. Good luck with your programming adventures!

Comment: I will - I need to wait 4 min to accept. Thanks.